# Mail Not Sending from My Server

Tags: email, php

I am having issues sending mail from my server, when I type in phpinfo() I get this:

```
Mail:     /var/spool/mail/frank 
...
_ENV["MAIL"]:    /var/spool/mail/frank
```

The php file that I'm using the Mail function in is owned by Apache and has 775 permissions. Inside /var/spool/mail there is no apache file, but there is a file for every other user on the box. Do I need to change the php.ini? Or can I add in an apache file (perhaps duplicate the frank file and then rename)?

Any advice can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/var/spool/mail` is where incoming unread mail is stored. There would be an 'apache' file only if the apache account has received mail.

Have you looked inside the MTA's log (usually `/var/log/maillog`) to see what's going on? If PHP's properly sending mail, there should be an entry in there for the mail being en-queued and what happened when the MTA (postfix/sendmail/exim/etc...) tries to forward it onwards.